# For all $1 \leq i < j \leq k$, the subtrees $T_i$ and $T_j$ have a vertex in common. Show that $T$ has a vertex which is in all of the $T_i$.

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, trees

Can someone please verify my proof or offer suggestions for improvement? I am aware that there is a similar question elsewhere, but I want help with my proof in particular.

> Let $T_1, \ldots, T_k$ be subtrees of a tree $T$ such that for all $1 \leq i < j \leq k$, the trees $T_i$ and $T_j$ have a vertex in common. Show that $T$ has a vertex which is in all of the $T_i$.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that for every vertex $v \in V(T)$, there is a subtree $T'$ in the list $T_1, T_2, \ldots, T_k$ such that $v \notin V(T')$.

Pick $v_1 \in T_1$. There is a subtree $T^{(1)}$ such that $v_1 \notin T^{(1)}$. $T_1$ and $T^{(1)}$ have a vertex $y_1$ in common. Now, there exists a tree $T^{(2)}$ such that $y_1 \notin T^{(2)}$. But now, $T^{(2)}$ and $T^{(1)}$ have a vertex $y_2$ in common. Also, $T_1$ and $T^{(2)}$ have a vertex $y_3$ in common.

There exists a path $p_1$ in $T_1$ from $y_3$ to $y_1$. Also, there is a path $p_2$ in $T^{(1)}$ from $y_1$ to $y_2$ and a path $p_3$ in $T^{(2)}$ from $y_2$ to $y_3$. Note that the path formed by the union of $p_1$ and $p_2$ passes through $y_1$, while $p_3$ does not, since $y_1 \notin T^{(2)}$. Therefore, the union of $p_1, p_2$, and $p_3$ forms a cycle, contradicting the fact that $T$ is a tree. Therefore, it must be the case that there is a vertex $x$ in all of the $T_i$.

Comment: We don't know that $y_2$ is in $T^{(1)}$, so your assertion "there is a path $p_2$ in $T^{(1)}$ from $y_1$ to $y_2$" doesn't seem justified.

Comment: @GregMartin My bad. I've corrected my proof.

Comment: See also Theorem 4.1 in: [W. A. Horn, *Three Results for Trees, Using Mathematical Induction*, Journal of Research of the National Bureau of Standards - B. Mathematical Sciences, Volume 76B, Nos. 1 and 2, January
-June 1972](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/76B/jresv76Bn1-2p39_A1b.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

Let $T_1'$ be a minimal subtree of $T_1$ such that $V(T_1')\cap V(T_j)\ne\emptyset$ for all $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. If $T_1'$ has only one vertex, we're done. Assume for a contradiction that $T_1'$ has more than one vertex. Then $T_1'$ has at least two leaves; let $x$ and $y$ be two distinct leaves of $T_1'$. By the minimality of $T_1'$, there are indices $i$ and $j$ such that $V(T_i)\cap V(T_1')=\{x\}$ and $V(T_j)\cap V(T_1')=\{y\}$. Since $T_i$ and $T_j$ have a common vertex, their union $T_i\cup T_j$ is connected. Let $P$ be the path from $x$ to $y$ in $T_i\cup T_j$, and let $Q$ be the path from $x$ to $y$ in $T_1'$. Since $V(P)\cap V(Q)=\{x,y\}$ and $E(P)\cap E(Q)=\emptyset$, $P\cup Q$ is a cycle in $T$, contradicting the assumption that $T$ is a tree.

**P.S.** In the question and answer above, trees are assumed to be finite. In a comment [SK19](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/509159/sk19) suggested generalizing the result to infinite trees. SK19 pointed out that the result fails if $T_1,T_2,\dots$ is an infinite decreasing sequence of *rays* (one-way infinite paths) with empty intersection. This is essentially the only counterexample.

In what follows, trees may be finite or infinite. A tree is *rayless* if it does not contain a sequence of distinct vertices $v_n$ ($n\in\mathbb N$) with $v_n$ adjacent to $v_{n+1}$ for each $n$.

**Lemma.** A chain of rayless trees has a nonempty intersection. (The intersection, of course, is a tree.)

**Proof.** Assume for a contradiction that $\mathcal C$ is a chain of rayless trees whose intersection is empty. Choose a tree $T_0\in\mathcal C$ and a vertex $x_0\in V(T_0)$. Having chosen a tree $T_n\in\mathcal C$ and a vertex $x_n\in V(T_n)$, next choose a tree $T_{n+1}\in\mathcal C$ not containing $x_n$ (so $T_{n+1}$ is a subtree of $T_n$ since $\mathcal C$ is a chain), and let $P_n$ be the path in $T_n$ from $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$. As the paths $P_0,P_1,P_2,\dots$ are internally disjoint, by concatenating them we get a ray in $T_0$, contradicting the fact that $T_0$ is rayless.

**Theorem.** Let $(T_i:i\in I)$ be a family of subtrees of a tree $T$. The intersection $\bigcap_{i\in I}V(T_i)$ is nonempty if and only if both of the following statements hold:
(a) $V(T_i)\cap V(T_j)\ne\emptyset$ for all $i,j\in I$;
(b) there is a rayless subtree $S$ of $T$ such that $V(S)\cap V(T_i)\ne\emptyset$ for all $i\in I$.

**Proof.** The "only if" is clear; we prove the "if". Suppose (a) and (b) hold; we have to show that $\bigcap_{i\in I}V(T_i)\ne\emptyset$.

Let $\mathcal P$ be the set of all subtrees $S'$ of $S$ such that $V(S')\cap V(T_i)\ne\emptyset$ for all $i\in I$. Then $\mathcal P$ is nonempty because $S\in\mathcal P$. Moreover, it follows from our lemma that every chain $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal P$ has a lower bound in $\mathcal P$, namely its intersection. (For $i\in I$, $\{S'\cap T_i:S'\in\mathcal C\}$ is a chain of rayless trees.) Therefore, by Zorn's lemma, $\mathcal P$ has a minimal element. Let $S_0$ be a minimal element of $\mathcal P$.

If $S_0$ has only one vertex, we're done. Assume for a contradiction that $S_0$ has more than one vertex. Then, since $S_0$ is rayless, it has at least two leaves (the endpoints of any maximal path in $S_0$); let $x$ and $y$ be two distinct leaves of $S_0$. By the minimality of $S_0$, there are indices $i,j\in I$ such that $V(T_i)\cap V(S_0)=\{x\}$ and $V(T_j)\cap V(S_0)=\{y\}$. Since $T_i$ and $T_j$ have a common vertex, their union $T_i\cup T_j$ is connected. Let $P$ be the path from $x$ to $y$ in $T_i\cup T_j$, and let $Q$ be the path from $x$ to $y$ in $S_0$. Since $V(P)\cap V(Q)=\{x,y\}$ and $E(P)\cap E(Q)=\emptyset$, $P\cup Q$ is a cycle in $T$, contradicting the assumption that $T$ is a tree.

**Corollary.** Let $(T_i:i\in I)$ be a family of subtrees of a tree $T$ such that $V(T_i)\cap V(T_j)\ne\emptyset$ for all $i,j\in I$. If $I$ is finite, or if $T_i$ is rayless for some $i\in I$, then $\bigcap_{i\in I}V(T_i)\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: If I read this correctly, the index set of the subtrees can have any cardinality and this proof would still work, right?

Comment: Ah, it is obviously false for infinite trees. Take the ray graph and as a subtree family all subrays.

Comment: I glanced over the minimality conclusion (existence of $i$ and $j$ with the properties) the first time reading your proof, but now I am wondering what the details are. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It would appear so, since a rayless non trivial tree has at least two leaves, so your first proof works again.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of the minimality of ordinals, but a tree with minimal order doesn't have to be minimal itself if the order is infinite. So Zorn's lemma seems to be required...

Comment: On the other hand, if we have a tree with minimal order we can make it minimal by repeatly removing all endvertices that are not minimal. We can remove infinite endvertices in one step if needed (which probably uses AC), and the process ends because otherwise we have found a ray.

Answer (score 5):

It suffices to prove the following lemma:

$\textbf{Lemma.}$ If $T_1, T_2, T_3$ are subtrees of a tree $T$ such that any two intersection is not empty, then all $3$ subtrees have a common vertex.

$\textbf{Proof.}$ Suppose no vertex lies in all $3$ trees. Then there exist distinct vertices $w_1, v_2, v_3$ in $T_2\cap T_3, T_3\cap T_1, T_1\cap T_2$ respectively, none of which belongs to their respective third tree.

So there exist a path $P \in T_3$ from $w_1$ to $w_2$. In this (unique) path, choose two vertices $x$ and $y$ in $P$ such that $x\in T_1$ and $y\in T_2$, and any vertex between $x$ and $y$ along $P$ are not in $T_1\cup T_2$. Note that $x$ and $y$ must necessarily be distinct by assumption, but are allowed to be adjacent.

Then we can define a path $Q$ from $x$ to $y$ in $T_1\cup T_2$, by taking the shortest path from the walk $x$ to $w_3$ to $y$ in $T_1\cup T_2$. This path $Q$ is disjoint from $P$ so $P\cup Q$ forms a cycle, a contradiction with $T$ being acyclic. $\square$

The problem now follows by induction: Suppose this is true for some $k\ge 3$, with base case $k=3$ proven above. Given $k+1$ subtrees with the given conditions, notice that for any $1\le i < j \le k$, $T_i\cap T_j$ is also a subtree of $T$. Indeed, if $x$ and $y$ are vertices in $T_i\cap T_j$, then take the unique path $P$ in $T$ from $x$ to $y$, $P$ must be in both $T_i$ and $T_j$ for it to be subtrees of $T$.

Now, note that by the lemma, $T_i\cap T_{k+1}$ and $T_j\cap T_{k+1}$ have a common vertex for all $i\neq j$, and are all subtrees of $T$. So we can apply the hypothesis on these subtrees to conclude they have a common vertex, hence so as the subtrees $T_1,\cdots T_{k+1}$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 4):

This proof is not correct.
Apart from the fact that you mix-up $T_1$ and $T^{(1)}$ there is a logic error: the statement "Therefore, the union of $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ forms a cycle"
needs justification.
You need an argument to exclude an example like:
$p_1=y_1vwy_3$ and $p_2=y_1vwy_2$ and $p_3=y_2wy_3$.

Comment: Is there an alternative proof you have in mind?

Comment: Hint: mathematical induction on the subtrees $T_1 \dots T_k$ may be a powerful approach.

Comment: You suggested that you already saw an alternate proof and just wanted an opinion about your own proof. This is called the 'Helly property for trees' and there are proofs all over the place.